# How to include plug-n-play widget statics [CSS/JS] without repetition?

Tags: php, python, django, templates, include

I have a reusable `google-maps` widget that can be plugged into any page that might want to use it.

**Widget has :**

- Google maps specific `js` includes.
- Map specific `css` to style the map.

**Problem:**

- Widget code gets included as `server-side` include.
- Widget specific `js` and `css` has to included with the widget code.
- Therefore, if widget repeats 5 times on a page, then the include statements for `js` and `css` get included 5 times.
- I can-not keep the widget specific includes in the `<head>` tag, since if the widget is not used on the page, then un-used `js` and `css` gets downloaded on client.

So, how should I keep the `js` and `css` so they gets included only when the widget is used and no multiple include are done in case the widget is repeated.

**My technology:**

- `Django-Python` [ If that matters ]
- I also faced the same problem on `php`

**Note :**

- I understand that including the same `js` and `css` multiple times on a page doesn't forces the client to download them multiple times, but I want to avoid the multiple includes.

**How should I tackle this problem ?**

Please feel free to ask for more info, if I missed something. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your use case a few options:

1. Use a separate base template for all pages that need the widget; in that base add the required js/css files.  For all views that need the widget, inherit from the modified base.
2. Using javascript implement conditional includes.

Comment: I know the work arounds, please suggest something without new base / conditional includes, etc. 

This must be a standard problem.

Comment: It doesn't seems practical to have a new base template for every possible combination of widgets with the pages.

Comment: Seems like no other solution :(